# a simple wp_enqueue_scripts that will replace "script src" in a wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

i am killing myself over this. looked all over the web. i am building a wordpress plugin and all i want is a proper code what will replace:

```
<script src="<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>/great-index/showhide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

i have tried:

```
        <?php
    function my_scripts_method() {
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'custom-script',
            plugins_url() . '/showhide.js',
            array( 'jquery' ) ); }
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' ); ?>
```

and many other 'wp_enqueue_script' codes... how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `plugins_url()`, try `get_template_directory_uri()`

```
<?php
    function my_scripts_method() {
      wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/showhide.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
      );
    }
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
?>
```